# GD LIbrary on a Mac: "undefined function Intervention\Image\Gd\imagecreatefrompng()"

Tags: php, macos, laravel, gd

I am facing some issues with GD in a laravel project. My phpinfo says that GD is enabled but I get an "undefined function Intervention\Image\Gd\imagecreatefrompng()" error.

[image]

I am facong the issues when I try to execute this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

  //Show the image
  echo '<img src="'.$_POST['img_val'].'" />';

  //Get the base-64 string from data
  $filteredData=substr($_POST['img_val'], strpos($_POST['img_val'], ",")+1);

  //Decode the string
  $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

  //Save the image
  $storagepath = storage_path('app/images/users/' . Auth::user()->id);
  $imgoutput = File::put($storagepath.'/flyer2.png', $unencodedData);


  return view('backend.flyers.index')->withImgoutput($imgoutput);
                                     //->withStoragepath($storagepath);

}
```

Comment: At what point in execution do you get the error message?

Comment: I am saving an image in a laravel project in a folder. When I try to view the image in my browser I receive the error message. Also Photoshop tells me that the file is corrupt.

Comment: If you have any code or settings relating to this problem, you should post them as well. I can't help you, since I don't know anything about laravel, but the better you write your question, the more likely that you will get an answer.

Comment: public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

  //Show the image
  echo '<img src="'.$_POST['img_val'].'" />';

  //Get the base-64 string from data
  $filteredData=substr($_POST['img_val'], strpos($_POST['img_val'], ",")+1);

  //Decode the string
  $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

  $storagepath = storage_path('app/images/users/' . Auth::user()->id);
  $imgoutput = File::put($storagepath.'/flyer.jpg', $unencodedData);

  return view('backend.flyers.index')->withImgoutput($imgoutput);
                                     //->withStoragepath($storagepath);
}

Comment: This is the function I am using to save an image. By trying to view it in my browser I receive the error message

Comment: Edit it into your question, and pay attention to some formatting, the code is unreadable in comments.

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: It might be a conflict with your namespace, try adding a backslash before your function call, such as `\imagecreatefrompng`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your GD installation doesn't have support for PNG images. That should be listed along the GD section of your `phpinfo()`.

Which PHP version are you using?

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php):

> To enable support for png add `--with-png-dir=DIR`. Note, libpng requires the zlib library, therefore add `--with-zlib-dir[=DIR]` to your configure line. As of PHP 7.4.0, `--with-png-dir` and `--with-zlib-dir` have been removed. **libpng and zlib are required**.

There's a chance you need to install `libpng` and `zlib` on your system.